# How XTestFakeKeyEvent combines events?

Tags: c, linux, x11, keyboard-events, keystroke

I need to send <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> keystrokes to get capital `A`. The only problem: I can't use `XTestFakeKeyEvent` (because it's an extension) and I don't want to pass <kbd>Shift</kbd> through an `event.state` (if possible). I tried 4 calls to `XSendEvent` which doesn't work. So I wonder: how `XTestFakeKeyEvent` does the same thing?

P.S: "my" code

```cpp
// Send a fake keystroke event to an X window.
// by Adam Pierce - http://www.doctort.org/adam/

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>


// Function to create a keyboard event
XKeyEvent createKeyEvent(Display *display, Window &win,
                         Window &winRoot, bool press,
                         int keycode, int modifiers)
{
    XKeyEvent event;

    event.display     = display;
    event.window      = win;
    event.root        = winRoot;
    event.subwindow   = None;
    event.time        = CurrentTime;
    event.x           = 1;
    event.y           = 1;
    event.x_root      = 1;
    event.y_root      = 1;
    event.same_screen = True;
    event.keycode     = XKeysymToKeycode(display, keycode);
    event.state       = modifiers; // I know here I can pass Shift explicitly
                                   // But is there a better way?
    if(press)
        event.type = KeyPress;
    else
        event.type = KeyRelease;

    return event;
}

main()
{
// Obtain the X11 display.
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(0);
    if(display == NULL)
        return -1;

// Get the root window for the current display.
    Window winRoot = XDefaultRootWindow(display);

// Find the window which has the current keyboard focus.
    Window winFocus;
    int    revert;
    XGetInputFocus(display, &winFocus, &revert);

// Send a fake key press event to the window.
    XKeyEvent event = createKeyEvent(display, winFocus, winRoot, true, XK_A, 0);
    XSendEvent(event.display, event.window, True, KeyPressMask, (XEvent *)&event);

// Send a fake key press event to the window.
    event = createKeyEvent(display, winFocus, winRoot, true, XK_Shift_L, 0);
    XSendEvent(event.display, event.window, True, KeyPressMask, (XEvent *)&event);

// Send a fake key release event to the window.
    event = createKeyEvent(display, winFocus, winRoot, false, XK_Shift_L, 0);
    XSendEvent(event.display, event.window, True, KeyPressMask, (XEvent *)&event);

// Send a fake key release event to the window.
    event = createKeyEvent(display, winFocus, winRoot, false, XK_A, 0);
    XSendEvent(event.display, event.window, True, KeyPressMask, (XEvent *)&event);

// Done.
    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the correct modifiers. Why are you looking for a "better" way?

Comment: Because I want users to be able to pass an arbitrary long sequence of keystrokes. If you pass through modifiers than you need to check every key in a sequence whether it's a modifier, then apply it to other non-modifier keys.

Comment: And `XTestFakeKeyEvent` does exactly the thing that I want. Why would I use modifiers if it's possibly to do the desired way?

Comment: Note: `Shift+A` is just an example. It may be `Ctrl+Shift+V`, just `A` or any other input you want.

Comment: `XTestFakeKeyEvent` emulates a physical keystroke to the server. The server then check every key in a sequence whether it's a modifier, exactly like it does with physical keys. Note `XTestFakeKeyEvent` *only* sends a keycode and nothing else. `XSendEvent` doesn't emulate a physical keystroke, it emulates one or more keystrokes that are already processed by the server, checked for modifiers, checked to which window they go, etc etc. So somebody needs to go and check for modifiers (and layout switches and whatnot). The server does not, it just sends the event you provide as is.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it. Thanks! Is it difficult to emulate physical keystroke by yourself?

Comment: You need either a custom keyboard driver, or an X extension.